# Code coverage : Tool for code coverage for apache storm topologies

Tags: code-coverage, jacoco, cobertura

Does anyone has any idea as to how can we configure code coverage for storm topologies?

We have about 5 topologies and we have to setup code coverage for these topologies.

Does Jacoco, cobertura works?

Comment: If Java, use Jacoco. If Gradle, download full dist zip of Gradle to see Examples of Gradle + Jacoco in few different scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was finally able to get coverage using Jacoco. 
I passed arguments to topology submission "**-javaagent:/var/lib/rdp/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.1.jar=destfile=/var/lib/rdp/jacoco/jacoco.exec,includes=com.ABC.***".

To generate the report I have to kill the topology and then generate html report from coverage file. Also to overcome killing part, am sending continuous coverage to a 3rd server.